# Encoding and decoding in Haskell -- 99 Problems exercise 13, 14

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, compression

I've been working on these solutions to the Haskell 99 questions, [encoding and decoding series](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/11_to_20) for a while now, so I figured I ought to present them to see how I screwed up the implementation.

Problems:

> Encoding: Write a function which encodes a series of characters using
>   run-length encoding and an algebraic data type such that the sequence
>   `"aaaabccaadeeee"` outputs:
>
> ```
> [Multiple 4 'a',Single 'b',Multiple 2 'c',Multiple 2 'a',Single 'd',Multiple 4 'e']
> ```
>
> Decoding: Write a function which decodes a series of algebraic data types  representing run-length encoding as a series of characters such that the sequence
>
> ```
> [Multiple 4 'a',Single 'b',Multiple 2 'c',Multiple 2 'a',Single 'd',Multiple 4 'e']
> ```
>
> outputs `"aaaabccaadeeee"`.

Here is the code I used for the problems:

```
import Data.List

main = do
    print $ decode (encode "Mississippi")


data Encoding = Multiple Int Char | Single Char deriving (Show)

encode :: [Char] -> [Encoding]

encode chars= map toEncoding ( (countChars . group) chars)

    where


    countChars :: [String] -> [(Int, Char)]
    countChars strings = map countCharsHelper strings

    countCharsHelper :: String -> (Int, Char)
    countCharsHelper chars = (length chars, head chars)

    toEncoding :: (Int, Char) -> Encoding
    toEncoding (1, a) = Single a
    toEncoding (num, a) = Multiple num a

decode :: [Encoding] -> [Char]

decode encodings = foldl (++) "" (map replicateChars (map fromEncoding encodings))
    where


    fromEncoding :: Encoding -> (Int, Char)
    fromEncoding (Multiple num char) = (num, char)
    fromEncoding (Single char) = (1, char)

    replicateChars :: (Int, Char) -> [Char]
    replicateChars (num, char) = replicate num char
```

And the output is the expected output "Mississippi", while decode and encode testing correctly via GHCi.

Comment: And what is the result of running that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea, which is to use `group` and `Data.List.group` and `replicate`, is right.  Your implementation is a bit verbose, though.

The top-level functions (`encode`, `decode`, and `main`) should have type signatures.  You didn't write one for `main :: IO ()`.  The inner functions, though, don't need type signatures, since the compiler can infer their types.

Avoid nesting parentheses.  All of your nested parentheses could be written with `$` instead.  For example:

```
print $ decode $ encode "Mississippi"
```

I don't think you need so many helper functions.

Both `encode` and `decode` could be written in point-free style.

Writing `decode = foldl (++) "" (map replicateChars (map fromEncoding encodings))` is too complicated.  [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) would do the trick.

```
import Data.List (group)

data Encoding = Multiple Int Char | Single Char deriving (Show)

encode :: String -> [Encoding]
encode = map toEncoding . group
  where
    toEncoding (c:[]) = Single c
    toEncoding group  = Multiple (length group) (head group)

decode :: [Encoding] -> String
decode = concatMap fromEncoding
  where
    fromEncoding (Single char)       = [char]
    fromEncoding (Multiple num char) = replicate num char

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ decode $ encode "Mississippi"
```

Comment: Small remark, using nested parentheses: they are considered to be better than `$` by some of the community, see [Gabriel's post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2015/09/how-to-make-your-haskell-code-more.html), as long as your code is intended _to be readable by non-Haskell programmers_.

Comment: Also, `toEncoding (c:[]) =` is rather verbose, compared to `toEncoding [c] =`.

Comment: My nested parentheses happen because I mostly treat like a very strange derivation of Lisp, so my initial programs usually look a lot more like a lisp-y language than haskell (so print decode... was actually (print (decode (encode "Mississippi")))), and I'm very concerned about using the composition and feeding (?) (I mean $) operators incorrectly, causing subtle bugs that the compiler doesn't say anything about (because it's error messages suck).


Also @Zeta, I had no idea that [c] worked in this context, as it is too similar to foo :: [a] -> [a]. I still prefer (c:[]) for readability.

Comment: Also, is it really necessary to provide a signature for main?